# Static pattern rules in Makefiles

Tags: makefile

I was looking at [Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) and I thought that the below would call first the `little` then the `big` target, but it stops after `big` with no attempts to proceed to `little`.

```
targets = bigoutput littleoutput

$(targets): %output : %
  @echo Done

little:
  @echo in little

big:
  @echo in big
```

Here's the output:

```
in big
big > bigoutput
```

I thought that the static pattern rules were the answer to being able to process multiple targets by following unique prerequisites for each. What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make's concept of the "default goal" is independent of everything else. No matter what you do, it always is only a single target.

To work around it, use `all: $(targets)` as the first line.

---

Static pattern rules are useful for a different purpose: when you have multiple generate files that have names that match the pattern, but need to be built using different rules.

Comment: Wow, I would never have thought of that as a solution. Thanks so much! I'll study that part of the docs more closely.